# unity how can I convert transform.position into physical movement?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, move

In my code I move the player with transform.position but this creates problems with colliders and the physic of my game.

```
 transform.position = new Vector3(
                transform.position.x + touch.deltaPosition.x * multiplier,
                transform.position.y,
                transform.position.z + touch.deltaPosition.y * multiplier)
```

How can I convert this to velocity or some physical movement so that the speed get not effect?

Comment: try handling the rigidBody component, that you should add to the game object: gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = speed; You give a speed to the gameeobject and the physics are handled for you according to rigidbody physics. If you are having problem with interaction of other physical objects you cna make it kinematic.

Comment: Please post a complete code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general as soon as there is a `Rigidbody` and collisions involved you should avoid two things:

- Moving your object via the `transform`
- Moving your object in `Update`

Both breaks the physics.

What you rather want to do is either directly update the [`Rigidbody.velocity`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html). It is fine to do that in `Update`

```
// If possible already reference via Inspector
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

private void Start()
{
    if(!_rigidbody) _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void Update()
{
    ...

    _rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.right * touch.deltaPosition.x * multiplier 
        + Vector3.forward * touch.deltaPosition.y * multiplier;
    ...
}
```

The alternative is to separate the User input (`Update`) from the physics routine (`FixedUpdate`) and use [`MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html)

(assuming your code is executed in Update)

```c#
private Vector3 targetPosition;

// If possible already reference via Inspector
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

private void Start()
{
    if(!_rigidbody) _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

    targetPosition = transform.position;
}

private void Update()
{
    ...

    targetPosition = _rigidbody.position 
        + Vector3.right * touch.deltaPosition.x * multiplier 
        + Vector3.forward * touch.deltaPosition.y * multiplier;

    ...
}

private void Update()
{
    _rigidbody.MovePosition(targetPosition);
}
```